# Subsite implementation in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a website in ASP.NET. Now I need to create subsites off this main site. These subsites share the same database, but use different master pages, themes, CSS, templates etc. How should I configure subsites in IIS?

Do i have to create subsites as separate projects? Or, is it possible to nest the subsites in the main project itself?

Comment: There are lots of different ways to accomplish this. What have you tried? How would you like it to work from a developer perspective? How would you like it to look from an end-user perspective?

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider a number of things:

- How many subsites are you going to have?
- Will subsites be provisioned manually, or automatically?
- Is a process boundary required? IIS applications and virtual directories can operate in different ways. A directory could be a subsite in some sites if the owner doesn't care about isolating code (or doesn't want the overhead.)
- How will developers be updating the site? Will they be managing each subsite with Visual Studio? You might want different permissions on the filesystem or even want to prevent any visibility of files in the parent site. You might want to consider how FTP (or better SSH) access is setup and enabled here too as this is tied to your overall problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can go either ways. 
You can create a separate folder under your site, that could act as your subsite and specify different master pages, themes, css, templates etc for the files in this folder.

But a cleaner implementation would be to have an actual subsite. That will be independent of the main site. So you create a different project with the required resources. The way to link this new project in IIS would be to right click and create a virtual directory (IIS 6) or right click and create a new application (IIS 7) under the parent website. And then point it to the new project path.

Since the two sites will share a common database, I also recommend creating a set of web services that access the data and each site could feed off of it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vishal Kumar.

Comment: No problem. If it helped, see if you can mark my answer likewise.